# Как правильно: упор на пениЕ или упор на пениИ?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, управление

Из статей:
1. *Или вы делаете **упор** только **на пение**?*
2. *На уроках музыки в белгородских школах будут делать **упор на пение.***

Из статей:
 1. *Итальянская опера делала **упор на пении,** а французская вырастала из балета...*
 2. *Церкви Христовы в Америке типично делают **упор на** общинном **пении** в церковных собраниях.*

Не смогла решить — **как** правильно? И есть ли какие-то **особенности** при выборе падежа?

Comment: Сначала удивился такому хорошему вопросу от новичка. И только потом заметил, что автор не новичок, а Римма. :)

Comment: А-ах спасибо за добрые слова. Два с лишним года назад я и была новичком. По сравнению с зубрами — считаю себя таковой до сих пор.

Answer (score 3):

В словаре управлений сказано, что оба варианта равнозначны:

Упор в сочетании с глаголом делать на что и на чем. Сделать упор на значение этого мероприятия. Упор сделан на роли комсомольской организации.

[упор | onlineslovari.com](http://onlineslovari.com/slovar_upravleniya/page/upor.2326/)

Я тоже не вижу никаких смысловых отличий,фразеологизм **делать упор** почти всегда сочетается с отвлечёнными существительными, мне удобнее употреблять на чём, потому что подспудно чувствуется второй вопрос - где? Где ты сделал акцент / упор? На чём именно?

Answer (score 2):

**Из словаря:**

[Сделать упор | academic.ru](http://phraseology.academic.ru/3251/%D0%A1%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80)

ДЕЛАТЬ УПОР **на чём, на что.** СДЕЛАТЬ УПОР **на чём, на что.** Обращать внимание, придавать особое значение чему-либо. **Делая упор** на внутреннем переживании, Фигнер достигал порою значительных художественных результатов (Э. Старк. Петербургская опера и её мастера). [Командующий:] Нужно **сделать упор** на освоение взаимодействия танков с пехотой (Б. Ромашов. Бойцы).

Из словаря Ушакова:** [Упор | Толковый словарь Ушакова](http://enc-dic.com/ushakov/Upor-80645.html)

Делать (сделать) упор **на кого-что или на ком-чем.** Упор должен быть сделан теперь **на людях, на кадрах, на работниках, овладевших техникой** (Сталин).

**КОММЕНТАРИЙ**

Итак, допускаются два падежа, но падежи имеют разное значение: **конкретно направленный В.п. и ненаправленный, рассредоточенный П.п.** В этой теме  они заменяют друг друга, но желательно определить ситуации, где один из падежей более предпочтителен.

Возможно, В.п. используется там, где предмет единственный и очень важный, он называет **конкретную цель деятельности.** Если же мы **просто выделяем его среди других предметов или этих предметов много**, то надо использовать П.п.

Comment: Используя Ваш комментарий, нашла:  УПОР  ( в сочетании с глаголом делать )  НА ЧТО  и  НА ЧЁМ.   Сделать упор на значение этого мероприятия.   Упор сделан на роли комсомольской организации.   
( Пунктуация и управление в русском языке. Д.Э. Розенталь )

Comment: Если я Вас правильно поняла, то руководствоваться при выборе падежа нужно общим смыслом и т.н. "расставленными акцентами"?

Comment: Я бы выделила смысл. К примеру: Актер делает упор на внутреннее переживание. Фраза с В.п.  не звучит, так как предмет отвлеченный, обобщенный,  неопределенный с точки зрения временных границ.  А если поставлен конкретная, четкая задача, то лучше подходит В.п.

Answer (score 0):

Упор (**на что?**) на пение, на подготовку и т.д. Винительный падеж.

Но что такое "упор" в этом значении? Это сосредоточение внимания **на чём-либо** - на пении, на подготовке и т.д. (а здесь уже предложный падеж). Поэтому иногда падежи и путаются.

Comment: В том-то всё и дело! А почему путаются? К любому из предложений можно задать как вопрос "на что?",  так и вопрос "на чём?" КАК определить: какой падеж использовать?

Comment: Ну, почему путаются... Упор на **что-то**, а внимание на **чем-то**. Разве нельзя перепутать? Да запросто.

>> *К любому из предложений можно задать как вопрос "на что?", так и вопрос "на чём?"* -- Нет. "Упор на чём-то" -- неправильное управление.